# row panelGrid over another row CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a panelGrid to show information. When I insert one button in the first row, the rest of the rows move down. If I insert the button the rest of the rows don't must be moved. What CSS properties I need use.
A picture of my panel:

[image]

Shadowed row is the first row. Next picture show the second row:
[image]

And I want to my panel look like this:
[image]

I have used **position:absolute** over the button but my page is responsive and when I resize the page, this property crash responsive design. So what properties I need to use for get my goal? I am using Primefaces.

Regards

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have? It's impossible to tell from images what the code solution might be.

Comment: Look at the client-side html apply the correct css. Effectively, this is not PrimeFaces related.

Comment: I am asking about CSS property allow me insert the button with move the row below. I will try modify and add my code but it is very scattered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a `div` wrapper for your button, and the button to be floated inside so the `div` does not take extra height.

```
<table>
  <tr class="first-row">
    <td>
      <div class="button-wrapper">
        <a class="some-button">+</a>
      </div>
      First row
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="second-row">
    <td>
    Second row  
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
.button-wrapper {
  float: right;
  height: 1px; // Fool the row by thinking that this div doesn't have height
}
.some-button {
  float: right;
}
```

This way, when the navigator renders the row, it thinks that the `div` child has only 1 px, so it does not expand vertically.

Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/z2L715ev/2/

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thank you so much, It works perfectly.